# powershell v2, use cmdlet with parameters known only at truntime

Tags: powershell-2.0

I need to use cmdlet but will only know what parameter to use at runtime.

for ex, I may need to call

```
Get-ChildItem -filter <string>
```

or

```
Get-childItem -exclude <string>
```

or

```
Get-childItem -recurse
```

etc.

but I will know only at runtime which of -filter  or -exclude  or -recurse or a combination of them be needed.

***[ Get-ChildItem is only an example to illustrate the need not the real thing ]***

is it possible to do this except by using a huge if-then-else structure ? is it possible to use a cmdlet selecting parameters at runtime ?

TIA, Peyre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using you example you can do it something like this:

```
Function test ($value , [switch]$paramA, [switch]$paramB)
{
    if ($paramA)
    {
        $cmd = "-filter $value"
    }

    if($paramB)
    {
        $cmd = "-exclude $value"
    }

    iex "dir $cmd"
}
```

to test it try it like this:

```
test -value *.ps1 -paramA
```

or

```
test -value *.ps1 -paramB
```